# ggplot same color but different labelling

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot two lines and two sets of points with ggplot. They should have the same color, but I want to label them separately in the legend. How can I do this?

I use this code:

```
ggplot(data_posterior, aes(x=x, y=mean)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=dim)) +
  geom_point(data=data_observed, aes(x=x, y=y, color=dim))
```

and get following plot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want different entries for the `geom_line` and the `geom_point` you need more categories, e.g. use `color = paste0(dim, "_point")` for the `geom_point`. This will add two more categories to your legend. Afterwards set the colors and/or labels via `scale_color_manual`. Finally, you could use the `override.aes` argument of `guide_legend` to tweak the legend keys, i.e. show lines for the line categories, shows points for the point categories.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on `mtcars`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = factor(am))) +
  geom_point(
    data = mtcars,
    aes(
      x = hp, y = mpg,
      color = paste0(factor(am), "_point")
    )
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = rep(c("blue", "red"), 2),
    labels = c("0", "1", "0 (Point)", "1 (Point)")
  ) +
  guides(
    color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(
      linetype = c(rep("solid", 2), rep("blank", 2)),
      shape = c(rep(NA, 2), rep(16, 2))
    ))
  )
```

[image]